# Omniauth Tumblr setup: Where can i find the setup credentials?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, omniauth, tumblr

I am using omniauth to register multiple user accounts from facebook, twitter and tumblr. I succesfully set up the connections to facebook and twitter, but i fail to connect to Tumblr.

The [omniauth homepage](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth) on github tells me it does work with Tumblr, but does'nt supply me with any documentation on this provider.

I don't know what credentials i have to use for the initializers/omniauth file. I don't have any consumer keys/secret; Tumblr does not even supply these keys.

Ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out Tumblr *does* have proper oauth 2 authentication. Strangely they managed to hide their application registration page. I couldn't find this page anywhere, not by googling 'Tumblr app registration' or anything. They don't even mention it in any of their api documentation (which I found pretty good on itself btw). It almost look like they do not even like 3rd party apps?

Eventually i found the registration page trough a php authentication tutorial. I will paste it here for future reference:

http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/register